# Real time data graph for form application with oxyplot

Tags: oxyplot

I work on real time data in a form application. My data will be work real time and it will slides as oscilloscope waves.

How can I do that? I just see Wpf example in library documents but I have to work form application.

I am rookie at oxyplot. Sorry about if I am wrong

Also I can use another graph library if you suggest.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using Visual Studio creating a WinForms application. If that the case I would use the Chart tool found under Data in the toolbox instead of OxyPlot.  When you drag it on, by default the name will be Chart1.  It will also have a generic series already added.  The following function will generate a smooth curve:

```
    private void GenerateCurve()
    {
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.Auto = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "SIN()";
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Degrees";

        // Set graph limits
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 200;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalAutoMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.IntervalAutoMode.FixedCount;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 90;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorTickMark.Enabled = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorTickMark.Interval = 10;

        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = -1;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 1;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IntervalAutoMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.IntervalAutoMode.FixedCount;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = .1;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MinorTickMark.Enabled = true;

        // Set spline instead of line
        chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Spline;

        // Generate points
        for (int x = 0; x < 1000; x++)
        {
            double y = Math.Sin(x);
            chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY((double)x, Math.Sin(x));
            if (chart1.Series[0].Points.Count > 100)
            {
                chart1.Series[0].Points.RemoveAt(0);
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = chart1.Series[0].Points[0].XValue;
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = x;
                Application.DoEvents();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }
    }
```